# Sorted data in groups

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

**Dataset:**

```
id  uid     activity    postid  
1   20      A           1
2   20      A           1
3   6       A           1
4   3       A           1
5   6       A           1
6   13      A           1
7   13      B           1
8   18      B           1
9   18      B           1
10  1       A           1
```

**Current Results:**

```
id  uid     uid_list        groupCount  activity    postid
9   18      18,13           3           B           1
1   20      1,13,6,3,20     7           A           1
```

**Expected Results:**

```
id  uid     uid_list        groupCount  activity    postid
9   18      18,13           3           B           1
10  1       1,13,6,3,20     7           A           1
```

The query I have:

```
SELECT
    id,
    uid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid ORDER BY id DESC) as uid_list,
    COUNT(*) as groupCount,
    activity,
    postid
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `user_activities`
    ORDER BY id DESC) as tbl
GROUP BY
    activity, postid
ORDER BY
    id DESC
```

I want to group by `activity` and `postid` while having the result in descending order by `id`. And want to have the latest `id` and `uid` for every group. I don't understand why this query doesn't return the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand `id` value is increasing. To get the latest values you could use an aggregate function `MAX()`.

Also, your inner query with ordering is unnecessary because the engine has to sort the resultset by `id` anyways when building result for `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

To retrieve `uid` for a particular `id` column you need to self join to the same table.

```
SELECT
    a.id, b.uid, a.uid_list, a.groupcount, a.activity, a.postid
FROM (
    SELECT
        MAX(id) as id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid ORDER BY id DESC) as uid_list,
        COUNT(*) as groupCount,
        activity,
        postid
    FROM user_activities a
    GROUP BY
        activity, postid
    ) a
    INNER JOIN user_activities b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: No dude, I can't get `MAX(uid)`, I need latest `uid` (latest by `id`). And no `uid` is not increasing, it is FK from another table.

Comment: My bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: Well its a nice approach and solves the problem as well. But I am curious why it doesn't sort the rows before grouping? Even after my subquery approach to sort them?

Comment: This is probably because you are ordering by a column that is not inside `group_concat`. Please try changing it to: `DISTINCT uid ORDER BY uid DESC`. You don't need to order it by `id` anyways if I understand correctly.

Comment: No no it will mess up everything :) I need to sort it by `id`. Anyways thanks for the smart solution.

Comment: It seems in the output that `uid` values inside `uid_list` are actually sorted according to `id DESC`. I have no way of testing it atm, but looking at your question it seems correct.

Comment: Yes it is correct, that's why I accepted it. I asked for why my query didn't workout, never said your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104108/discussion-between-consider-me-and-shaharyar).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method is the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) as id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(uid ORDER BY ID DESC), ',', 1) as uid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uid ORDER BY id DESC) as uid_list,
       COUNT(*) as groupCount,
       activity, postid
FROM user_activities ua
GROUP BY activity, postid
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

There are some limitations to this approach, in the sense that `GROUP_CONCAT()` has a maximum length for the intermediate value.  Typically the default is sufficient, but you might need to change that value if many, many rows match each group (and you already have this issue for the list of `uid`s anyway).

Comment: What is the default length for `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Comment: @Shaharyar . . . http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len.  I emphasize that this affects your existing `group_concat()` as well as the second one proposed here.